# web api get user info inside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm using the standard owin asp.net.identity mechanism to authorize users using their access token. Inside my controller I would like to find out who has sent the request. How could I do it? Could I somehow retrieve the access token from the request inside my controller?

I have tried:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] GetParameters parameters)
{
   Var identity = RequestContext.Principal.Identity;
}
```

It does not give me a lot as majority of properties are always null.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string token = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Token.ToString();
```

Comment: That returns "Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeAccessTokenHandle"